# Is it possible to create an .IMG image of my disk without another disk?

Tags: linux, image, dd

I only have one disk and it has lots free space unused with only one primary partition. I want to create a .img image as a backup without free space.
i do some search on 'create img image'(without free space), most anwser give:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb | gzip > backup.img.gz
```

Now I have two question:

1. I only have one disk(sda) with all space in one partition(sda1), is it possible to create a .img image with the `dd` order without adding another disk? If 'yes', then what should i do? Running `dd if=/dev/sda | gzip > backup.img.gz` at `/home/xxx` will be ok? will `dd` copy the .img file itself to the iamge?
2. It's better to get a .img file, not a .img.gz file, without free space. is that possible in my condition(one disk)?

here's the condition of my computer(sorry for the system language):

```
root@act-Precision-T1500:/home/act# df
df: "/mnt/udisk": 输入/输出错误
文件系统           1K-块     已用      可用 已用% 挂载点
udev             1983824        4   1983820    1% /dev
tmpfs             400464     1252    399212    1% /run
/dev/sda1      476502040 64401980 387872068   15% /
none                   4        0         4    0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                5120        0      5120    0% /run/lock
none             2002320      180   2002140    1% /run/shm
none              102400       40    102360    1% /run/user
root@act-Precision-T1500:/home/act# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = 扇区 of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000d1403

   设备 启动      起点          终点     块数   Id  系统
/dev/sda1   *        2048   968466431   484232192   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       968468478   976771071     4151297    5  扩展
/dev/sda5       968468480   976771071     4151296   82  Linux 交换 / Solaris
```

Do i express myself clearly? I'm a beginner to Linux and my English is awful. Thank you for helping me！

Comment: Of course the disk image in `backup.img` would not contain `backup.img`.

Comment: I don't have time to put this in an answer, but here it goes: You can shrink your current partition(sda5) to only a little more than the used space, then in the free space you can create a new partition, and use DD to create the image of sda5 on the new partition. Alternatively, you can use a LVM snapshot (if your partition uses LVM, I can't tell). **Short answer is YES, but it's tricky and I would not recommend it for beginners**. Also, I think this is not the site to ask, maybe SuperUser. Your English is fine.

Comment: @Sorin useful for a beginner. (I even don't know SuperUser.) thank you very much!

Comment: As already said, it's tricky: you would copy data from a disk, while writing to the that disk itself. Depending on the kind of file system you can expect anything. I think 99,9% of the times you will get a workable image with just some error on it. It would be far better to create the image in another partition though.

Comment: ...moreover, physical images are not the best, they are little portable. A tar file (gzipped) or similar is more versatile: you can easily inspect it, extract partially, even on a different file system. Drop the image format.

Comment: @linuxfan there is no way that using a single partition would work with dd.  please do not confuse beginners!